# php não mostra mensagens de erro

Tags: php, recuperação-de-erros

Bom dia.
No início de minha página php coloquei:

```
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("log_errors_max_len",2048);
```

Após estas diretivas, dei um phpinfo().
display_errors e display_startup_erros estão marcados como On na coluna Local Value.
Ocorre que as mensagens de erro não são mostradas de jeito nenhum.
Tirei o ponto-e-virgula do final de uma linha e a página fica em branco, não mostrando a mensagem de erro que me ajudaria a localizar o problema.

Já tentei mudar de php5.6 para php 7 mas também não adiantou.
Estou rodando esta página hospedada na Locaweb.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda, por favor?
Muito obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de tentar exibir erros na página, considerando que é uma hospedagem, o mais recomendado é direcionar os erros para um arquivo e inclusive mensagens customizadas como abaixo:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/caminho/onde/guardar/php-error.log");
error_log( "POST: " . print_r($_POST, true) );
```

Assim você não corre o risco de deixar dados de depuração na página por acidente.